# How to use Inherited property for protocol compliance

Tags: swift, objective-c

I have an Objective-C ClassA:

```objectivec
@class ClassA;
     
@property (nonatomic, retain) String *str;
    
@end
```

Which then is inherited by a Swift class ClassB:

```swift
class ClassB: ClassA {
    
}
```

Separately, I will have a protocol:

```swift
protocolDelegate: AnyObject {
    var str: String
}
```

I will then try to extend ClassB to adhere to the protocolDelegate:

```swift
extension ClassB: protocolDelegate {
}
```

I have tried many ways of doing this but I can't get it to work. Is there a way to use the inherited property to conform to the protocol?

Comment: Post real Objective-C and real Swift code that properly demonstrates your issue. There are too many issues with the code you posted to determine the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The situation that you are describing should work. There are quite a few incorrect pieces in your code though.

The Objective-C class is usually defined by interface in a header and you need to use `NSString` to represent a `String` for Swift.

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
@end
```

Next your protocol is missing some pieces. It should look like

```
protocol ProtocolDelegate: AnyObject {
    var str: String { get }
}
```

And now I can easily declare a class such as

```
class ClassB: ClassA { }

extension ClassB: ProtocolDelegate { }
```

And this works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`, which has a property named `str`, you can use that inherited property to fulfill the protocol requirement. However, there are a couple of issues in your code that need to be addressed

- Incorrect protocol declaration: The protocol declaration is missing the name. It should be protocol protocolDelegate: AnyObject { ... }.
- Incorrect property declaration in ClassA: The property declaration in ClassA is using an invalid type String. In Objective-C, you would typically use NSString instead. Additionally, the property should use copy instead of retain for string types.

```
// Objective-C ClassA

@class ClassA;

@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *str;

@end
```

Your code for the protocol should be like

```
// Protocol protocolDelegate
protocol protocolDelegate: AnyObject {
    var str: String { get }
}
```

You can define your `ClassB` like this

```
Declaration of your class,
// Swift ClassB
class ClassB: ClassA {

}
```

And `ClassB` should confirm the protocol

```
// Conform ClassB to protocolDelegate
extension ClassB: protocolDelegate {

}
```